# unable to search child object fields in azure search services(documentdb)?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cognitive-search

I am very new to azure search, basically i have created database and one collection this collection have few documents, also i have created one index .

I am using REST API to search documents,
1) **my rest api service is given below**.

```
 GET  https://xxxx.search.windows.net/indexes/[xxx]/docs?search=xxx&searchFields=xxxx&api-version=2015-02-28
```

2) **My document is**:{
      "abc":"abcvalue",
       "xyz": {
              "key":"value",
               "kay1":"value1"
            }
    }

**Search result out put is :** 
{
    "@odata.context": "https://xxx.search.windows.net/indexes('xxx')/$metadata#docs(id,key,key1)",
    "value": [
        {
            "@search.score": 1,
            "id": "ccc485a8-18ea-8f06-9582-80a35ee9c567",
            "key": null,
            "key1": null
        },
        {
            "@search.score": 1,
            "id": "bad34bb1-ed9a-bfb9-46e9-be97ac52680c",
            "key": null,
            "key1": null
        }
}

but we are unable to search child object(xyz) fileds, where iam missing can you any one suggest me are any links

Thanks.

Comment: Rather than provide us with the call to your REST API, please provide the query you are sending to DocumentDB.

Comment: I am not sending the query,  basically what is the supported model  for Multi-level document search, present  azure search?

Comment: Please see the response to the related question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39640608/what-is-the-supported-model-for-multi-level-document-search

Answer (score 1):

In short, an Azure Search index can only have flattened documents at this time. This means you will need to take the hierarchical data in your DocumentDB and flatten it out in Azure Search. There's a really great article that discusses flattening your data [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/search-howto-complex-data-types/).

I hope this info helps,

Chad Campbell

Author of [Adding Search Abilities to your Apps with Azure Search](https://www.ecofic.com/courses/adding-search-abilities-to-your-apps-with-azure-search)